# Sporadically occurring kernel panic

Tags: macos, mac, kernel, kernel-panic

I'm getting kernel panics on a 2013 iMac with the latest OS 10.13 (High Sierra) installed.

All the loaded kexts in the log are from Apple.

I've determined it's a software problem, as I tried restoring a time-machine backup of the machine to another iMac, and that iMac still gets kernel panics.

---

This is what the log looks like:

```
Anonymous UUID:       BF6CFBAD-70DB-3DCE-F692-C70768EED2A3
Fri Nov 17 12:29:53 2017
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff80172b47b4): "Invalid waitq: 0"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570.20.62/osfmk/kern/waitq.c:4979
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9205203b50 : 0xffffff801726b6f6
0xffffff9205203ba0 : 0xffffff8017396f54
0xffffff9205203be0 : 0xffffff8017388c39
0xffffff9205203c60 : 0xffffff801721d190
0xffffff9205203c80 : 0xffffff801726b1cc
0xffffff9205203db0 : 0xffffff801726af4c
0xffffff9205203e10 : 0xffffff80172b47b4
0xffffff9205203e50 : 0xffffff8017704dab
0xffffff9205203ea0 : 0xffffff8017704b16
0xffffff9205203f00 : 0xffffff8017709544
0xffffff9205203f40 : 0xffffff801780da48
0xffffff9205203fa0 : 0xffffff801721d976
BSD process name corresponding to current thread: lsof
Mac OS version:
17B48
Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 17.2.0: Fri Sep 29 18:27:05 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.20.62~3/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B214D53-883B-3E5F-A115-9FDA17E68BA8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000017000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8017200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8017100000
System model name: iMac14,2 (Mac-27ADBB7B4CEE8E61)
System uptime in nanoseconds: 7033536507794

last loaded kext at 6791318167635:     com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost  8.1.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9ac06000, size 49152)
last unloaded kext at 6905394817132: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub  900.4.1 (addr 0xffffff7f9abb3000, size 12288)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost 8.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.2
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 127
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.24
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    131
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   280.12
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   280.12
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.16.19
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.1f1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.GeForce   10.2.6
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD5000Graphics   10.2.8
com.apple.AVEBridge 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    211
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferAzul  10.2.8
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.10.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    439.20.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  329
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1200.26.1a3
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   183
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.IOBufferCopyEngineTest    1
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  1004.1
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    1000
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 127
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.1f1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 280.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    526
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    600.15
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal    10.2.6
com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman  10.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.16.19
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 280.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.16.19
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    374.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   209
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   517.17
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    517.17
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   203
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.1f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   6.0.1f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.1f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.1f1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    546
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  301.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    288
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    439.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  140
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   404.20.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   404.20.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBufferCopyEngineFamily    1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCRTC    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
EOF

Model: iMac14,2, BootROM IM142.0123.B00, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 3.2 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.15f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M, PCIe, 1 GB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,         0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x111),                 Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.2.1a3)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.0f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD0128F, 121.33 GB
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD WD10EZES-40UFAA0, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Elements 10B8
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: iPhone
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 23.10
```

Comment: Such problems had as a final solution in many cases only the reinstallation of the OS.